# Mean of Groups of means in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data

Exp = my data frame

```
dt<-data.table(Game=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,3)),
               Round=rep(1:3,4),
               Participant=rep(1:4,each=3),
               Left_Choice=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
               Total_Points=c(5,15,12,16,83,7,4,8,23,6,9,14))

> dt
    Game Round Participant Left_Choice Total_Points
 1:    1     1           1           1            5
 2:    1     2           1           0           15
 3:    1     3           1           0           12
 4:    1     1           2           1           16
 5:    1     2           2           1           83
 6:    1     3           2           0            7
 7:    1     1           3           0            4
 8:    1     2           3           0            8
 9:    1     3           3           1           23
10:    2     1           4           1            6
11:    2     2           4           1            9
12:    2     3           4           1           14
```

Now, I need to do the following:

1. First of all for each of the participants in each of the  Games I need to calculated the mean "Left Choice rate".
2. After that I want to break the results to 5 groups (Left choice <20%,
   left choice between 20% and 40% e.t.c),
3. For each group (in each of the games), I want to calculate the **mean** of the Total_Points **in the last round - round 3 in this simple example **** [ONLY the value of the round 3] - so for example for participant 1, in game 1, the total points are in round 3 are 12. And for Participant 4, in game 2 it is 14.

So in the first stage I think I should calculate the following:

```
Game Participant Percent_left    Total_Points (in last round) 

1        1           33%            12
1        2           66%            7 
1        3           33%            23   
2        4           100%           14
```

And the final result should look like this:

```
Game  Left_Choice Total_Poins (average)    
    1         >35%                   17.5= (12+23)/2
    1     <35%<70%                   7
    1         >70%                   NA
    2         >35%                   NA
    2     <35%<70%                   NA
    2         >70%                   14
```

Please help! :)

Comment: You don't provide a data example so there may be little interest in building one for yu when it's not clear what structure you are working with. To me I appears that your first step will loos all the information about Rounds, since that was not one of the grouping fields.

Comment: @BondedDust unless someone is really trying to avoid their own work =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in `data.table`

1: simple group mean with `by`

```
dt[,pct_left:=mean(Left_Choice),by=.(Game,Participant)]
```

2: use `cut`; not totally clear, but I think you want `include.lowest=T`.

```
dt[,pct_grp:=cut(pct_left,breaks=seq(0,1,by=.2),include.lowest=T)]
```

3: slightly more complicated group mean with `by`

```
dt[Round==max(Round),end_mean:=mean(Total_Points),by=.(pct_grp,Game)]
```

(if you just want the reduced table, use `.(end_mean=mean(Total_Points))`instead).

You didn't make it clear whether there is a global maximum number of rounds (i.e. whether all games end in the same number of rounds); this was assumed above. You'll have to be more clear about this in order to provide an exact alternative, but I suggest starting with just defining it round by round:

```
dt[,end_mean:=mean(Total_Points),by=.(pct_grp,Game,Round)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a magic!   There is just one small problem in part 3 - for some reason the "max(round)" does not work - but if I substitute it with the actual number of the last round - than it does work..so the part 3 should be: dt[Round==3,end_mean:=mean(Total_Points),by=.(pct_grp,Game)]

Comment: reason it doesn't work--typo! should have been `Round`; fixed.

Comment: it still does not work... don't know why "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Round' not found".     Regarding the second part that you mentioned; dt[,end_mean:=mean(Total_Points),by=.(pct_grp,Game,Round)], is there a way to know how many participants I have in each of the groups?  Thanks!!

Comment: look at the output of `names(dt)` and make sure it's spelled correctly. As to numbering your participants, use `dt[,grp_size:=.N,by=pct_grp]` (or replace `pct_grp` with whatever grouping you had in mind)